# Chrome and input date

Tags: html, google-chrome, date, input, webkit

I saw that in the latest version of Chrome the 'clear button' (`-webkit-clear-button`) has been removed from the `input[date]`
Someone can advise me how to get it back that I can't find any information about webkit

Thanks